# In SSIS how to segment a Data Source into multiple RAW files

Tags: ssis

I have a stored procedure that returns around 10 million rows for a month ordered by date.  I would like to create a RAW file that includes the records for each day.

Is there a way to stream the records into a Raw file until the date changes and then close that RAW file and create a new RAW file for the next day and begin inserting records into the new RAW file?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your source query looks like `SELECT * FROM MySource WHERE ActionDate > '2019-11-01' AND ActionDate < '2019-12-01';`  I'd likely structure my data flow as OLE DB Source -> Conditional Split (on month's day) -> 31 Raw File Destinations. Every day, we'd rewrite the raw files with either blanks or actual data.

If I misread the question and you'd like to just fill a file for the current day's data, I'd filter my source data to only pull today's data. You can have the package create the raw file, just specify that it's "[Create always](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/raw-file-destination?view=sql-server-ver15)"

You can then rotate files in based on day number in case you need to keep previous raw file data.

Comment: If I misunderstood the question and I'm not addressing the problem, let me know and I can update/delete this answer